# Creating 'settings' view equivalent to the system views

Tags: android

I'd like to create a 'settings' tab in my Android application which will look like views in Android's system settings - for example like a `Phone settings > Sound`.

I'd like to achieve that headers, checkbox/radio list elements but I have no idea how to bite that.

When I create that UI elements in my XML definition of UI, they does not looks well.

Please suggest me a correct way to do that ane provide me some examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic word to search is `preference`

A random link to set you up : http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences